# Reactjs: update specific row

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I would like suggestions on the most efficient way to implement a price  / depth ladder GUI in Reactjs.

Each ladder represents a single stock and each row represents the available sizes and traded amounts for each price:

[image: price ladders]

The solution I have currently uses a list (stored in class.state) to render the rows of the stock table. Each item in this list represents a row in the stock table. Each render iterates over this list to output the tables show in the picture.

```
    var items = [];
    for (const sid in this.state.stocks) {
        const rows = this.state.stocks[sid];
        items.push(
            <div key={sid} style={{float: 'left'}}>
                <Ladder
                    rows={rows}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
    // doRender
    return (
        < div id={'container'}>
            {items}
        </div>
    );
`
```

The prices are updating frequently and the gui is struggling to keep up. I believe this is because each update redraws all table rows. Either way, my solution is not performing well under load.

I want to optimise updates and ensure only the affected rows are rendered / processed.

Comment: Can you add a sample of `this.state.stocks`?

Comment: What is runnerId, it should be sid?

Comment: hi,        this.state = {
            stocks: {},
 }
  
 where each row has 4 fields (key'd on price):
   price, buy, sell, traded

Comment: changed to sid, thanks

Comment: is the cell getting its value updated or new rows are getting deleted/added, also are you trying to keep track of running sum?

Comment: New price / size values are coming in on a web socket, which triggers a call to setState, this setState call triggers the render code noted above. 
The gui does not keep track of running sum.

Comment: I think key is the important thing here if you can somehow attach an key that depends on the value in the cell , react diffing algorithm will take care of performance itself

Comment: stack26, can you elaborate please?
... are you suggesting a key which combines price-buy-sell?
How does this stop render from iterating through all items? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To increase the performance of the UI, I would suggest following things:

1. Ladder needs to not re-render when there is no changes in rows. You can make it as a component with shouldComponentUpdate to comparing rows or pure component and use recompose utils to do so.
2. If you gonna have many rows for each Ladder, then should not do the deep comparisons (which consumes resource), but just comparing the instance itself, like:

> ```
> shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
>    return this.props.rows !== nextProps.rows;
> }
> ```

to do that, you'll need to update the rows correctly. If there is any row changed, then the ladder's rows need to be a new array, otherwise, keep the same array object.

3. The row also needs to be a component with shouldComponentUpdate to make sure, there is no re-render happens if no need.
4. It looks like that your data structure is quite complicated, so try to use redux and you'll be better at testing it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will add shouldComponentUpdate and cache the rows to enable object comparison. 
I may come back to you with additional questions on whether a single row change requires a full ladder render after adding shouldComponentUpdate methods down the call stack.